# How to use void pointers/typecasting for implementation of a doubly_linked_list class

Tags: c++, oop, casting, doubly-linked-list, void-pointers

I have an assignment in which I have to implement a doubly linked list ADT. I do not have issues with that, I created something like this:

```
class DoublyLinkedList{
    struct Node{
        int value;
        Node* next; 
        Node* back;
    };
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int count;
    Node* GetNewNode(int data);
    Node* NodeByIndex(int index);

public:
    DoublyLinkedList(){
        head = nullptr;
        head = nullptr;
    }

    // and then all the member functions. I am not including here the definitions, just declarations

    void insertFront( int data );
    void insertRear( int data );
    int removeFrontInt();
    int removeRearInt();
    int size( );
    void makeEmpty();
    void print();
    bool insertAt( int data, int index );
    int removeAt(int index);
    int findIndex( int data );
};

int main(){
    DoublyLinkedList list;

    list.insertFront(1);
    list.insertFront(2);
    list.insertFront(3);
    list.insertRear(100);
    list.insertRear(200);
    list.insertRear(300);

    std::cout << "List: " << "\t";
    list.print();
    std::cout << "Size of the list: " << list.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Removing first number in the list... " << std::endl;
    list.removeFrontInt();
    std::cout << "Removing last number in the list... " << std::endl;
    list.removeRearInt();
    return 0;
}
```

The professor included an optional section of the assignment:

> As an option if you want the list to be more useful you can have the node accommodate a pointer to a void instead of an integer. Then you can store any data not just integers provided you push and pop a pointer to the data and not the data itself. If you make this change then you can add the following functions.
>
> ```
> void insertFront( void *data );
> void insertRear( void *data );
> void * removeFrontPtr( );
> void * removeRearPtr( );
> ```
>
> and make the data a pointer to a void as opposed to a simple integer.
> To insert and remove an object you will use the following. Given the following declaration:
>
> `Class SomeClassType someObject, *ptrToSomeObject;`
>
> To insert pass the address of the object:
>
> `insertFront(&someObject );`
>
> To remove type cast back to a pointer to the original data type:
>
> `ptrToSomeObject = (SomeClassType *)removeFrontPtr( );`
>
> You can adapt the Option1 functions to use void pointers as well. Note there are no points for this part as this is only if you feel like you want a more useful list class for your future library.

I am lost with this. I have no idea how this would work, because, for example, don't you need to know the data type of the user input to typecast it? I just really have no idea. Any help is appreciated, even is it is a link to an article or a video, or just an explanation.

Comment: *"don't you need to know the data type of the user input to typecast it"* Yes, you need to know the type. What they want you to do is simple, just replace `int value` (aka `int data`) with `void *value`. It's not a good approach though (this is something you would do in C, and even there it would be questionable). You should rather make `DoublyLinkedList` a `template`.

Comment: @Amolgorithm Being able to pass a negative index is no different from being able to pass an index that is too large.

Comment: please post something we could compile...

Comment: @Thalia *if you want the list to be more useful you can have the node accommodate a pointer to a void instead of an integer* -- It seems your professor is not a C++ programmer, or at the very least, a C programmer teaching C++.  It is done by using templates in C++, and not using void pointers.  Basically all you need to do is take your working code, have `template <typename T> DoublyLinkedList { struct Node { T value; Node* next; Node *prev; };`, and wherever you were using `int data`, replace it with `T data`.

Comment: @Thalia [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/bxjGexYW3).  You will need to fill in the missing function body and functions.  Also note that the function bodies must be part of the `DoublyLinkedList` header file, and not in a separate .cpp file.  That is how you get this done generically in C++, and that is by using templates, not void pointers.